# How to get information from parent process in Python 3.9 multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I built a simple multiprocessing program in Python. It worked perfectly in Python3.7, but since the upgrade to 3.9 I'm struggling to understand how to make it work now multiprocessing has changed.

The program follows roughly the following pattern:

```
import multiprocessing

def print_multiprocessing(my_string):
    print(my_prefix, my_string)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    output = []

    for x in range(10):
         output.append(x)
    
    my_prefix = input()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    pool.map_async(print_multiprocessing, output, )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The actual program is more complicated obviously, but this will demonstrate my issue.

In Python3.7, the child processes would automatically inherit the `my_prefix` variable from the parent, but now in 3.9 that variable isn't available for the child process.

I could declare the variable outside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` which would mean it gets declared by each child process, but this means I'd have to call the `input()` function for every child process.

My current workaround is to have the `print_multiprocessing` function accept a list as an argument, and pass in every value I need as part of that list, but it feels very messy, especially when dealing with multiple data types.

Is there a simple trick I'm missing here?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here, and assuming you're using MacOS? Python 3.8 changed the default "start method" from "fork" to "spawn". Fork lets you get away with stuff like that, but it's bad practice to implicitly share global variables. "spawn" is more strict due to it being a more isolated environment (which is actually a good thing in terms of thread safety)

Comment: Manually changing back to "fork" *will* work, but it generally should be reserved for use when you really know what you're doing, and you need the memory / cpu savings over "spawn". There are whole classes of bugs that are hard to debug / eliminate using fork that are entirely solved with spawn. MacOS in particular has issues with OS frameworks not being fork-safe (because they are already multi-threaded).

Comment: [Shared ctypes Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects)

Comment: ... http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing ...

Comment: A queue could be used to pass the information. The information could be written to a file then retrieved by the child process.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for that, yes I'm on MacOS. Given I'm holding most of the machines I'm using this on on Python3.7 until I find a solution, I think multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork") would not be the worst solution for now.